# Python - how to get updated link that was passed as an argument?

Tags: python

I'm passing a link as an argument in a thread, that I want to scrape the timestamp on.  But in the function that the thread is pointing to, the timestamp  value does not change, every time i'm rescraping it.  How do you get timeLink to be dynamic and change every time it goes over the while loop? Here is the code:

```
def abcStart(timeLink):

    while True:
        res = timeLink
        res.raise_for_status()
        timestamp = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser').find_all('b')

        if timestamp[0].text == otherTimestamp[0].text:
            work on something
            break
        if timestamp[0].text > otherTimestamp[0].text:
            continue
        else:
            print('not yet')
        time.sleep(30)
    break

timelink = requests.get('http://example.com/somelink')

threadobj = threading.Thread(target=abcStart, args=(timelink))
threadobj.start()
threadobj.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is only one http request being sent. On this line:

```
timelink = requests.get('http://example.com/somelink')
```

the abcStart() function is receiving the http response, and using that one value the whole time it is running. This will cause us to scrape the same page every time. If we want to have a different page to scrape for each loop iteration, we need to perform another http request each time. Something like this:

```
def abcStart(timeLink):

while True:
    res = requests.get(timeLink) # send request here
    res.raise_for_status()
    timestamp = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser').find_all('b')

    if timestamp[0].text == otherTimestamp[0].text:
        work on something
        break
    if timestamp[0].text > otherTimestamp[0].text:
         continue
    else:
        print('not yet')
    time.sleep(30)
break

timeLink = 'http://example.com/somelink' # declare url

threadobj = threading.Thread(target=abcStart, args=(timelink))
threadobj.start()
threadobj.join()
```

Comment: Yes of course! Why didn't I think of that.  I just confirmed that this works.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should move timeLink request inside your function:

```
def abcStart(timeLink):

    while True:
        res = requests.get('http://example.com/somelink')
        res.raise_for_status()
        timestamp = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser').find_all('b')

        if timestamp[0].text == otherTimestamp[0].text:
            work on something
            break
        if timestamp[0].text > otherTimestamp[0].text:
            continue
        else:
            print('not yet')
        time.sleep(30)
    break

threadobj = threading.Thread(target=abcStart, args=())
threadobj.start()
threadobj.join()
```

Comment: I need to pass it as an argument because I need to do multithreading, and each thread will need to point to the same function but pass it different links.